# Angular 2D Array not updating table rows and columns accordingly

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I was having some problem when trying to initialize 2D array based on different condition in Angular Typescript. Here is my TypeScript:

```
selectSvcNoTable: any[][] = [];

const numofOrder = Number(value); // value here update according to input number
if (this.selectedSvcTy === this.SVC_TYP_IPHONENET) {
      this.selectSvcNoTable = [[new Array(numofOrder)], [new Array(3)]];
} else {
      this.selectSvcNoTable = [[new Array(numofOrder)], [new Array(1)]];
}
```

In my HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of selectSvcNoTable; let rowIdx = index;">
    <td *ngFor="let col of row; let colIdx = index;">         
    </td>
```

However, the table only shows two rows regardless on the value I set in 'numofOrder'. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
[[new Array(numofOrder)], [new Array(3)]]
```

This syntax results in :

```
[
  [
    [0, 1, 2]
  ], [
    [0, 1, 2]
  ]
]
```

You don't have a 2D array but a 3D array.

Try this instead :

```
selectSvcNoTable: any[][] = [];

const numofOrder = Number(value); // value here update according to input number
if (this.selectedSvcTy === this.SVC_TYP_IPHONENET) {
      this.selectSvcNoTable = [new Array(numofOrder), new Array(3)];
} else {
      this.selectSvcNoTable = [new Array(numofOrder), new Array(1)];
}
```

Comment: Hey can I check with you how do I loop your suggested 2D array in the HTML?

Comment: @hyperfkcb not sure you need to, but if you want to, sure, just make another question with a [mcve] and I'de be happy to help

Comment: I think it is still under the same question. What I am trying to do is from the 2D array populated, loop thru each of them to create a table. Basically what my selectSvcNoTable is something like this [row, column];

Comment: @hyperfkcb then provide a [mcve] here. And it's just HTML array building, I'm not sure you need me, you should be able to do that in like 5 minutes.

Comment: Hey the solution provided kept increasing in column instead of row. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No I don't. You didn't explain what you tried to do, I don't know what you're trying to display. That's why I need a [mcve].